# Probability of finding particle in ground state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

A particle is in a one dimensional infinitely deep square well, from 0 $\leq x \leq L$. Find the probability of finding the particle in the ground state of the square well if the wave function for a particle of mass $m$ is given by $\Psi(x) = Nx$.

I'm not really sure how to go about this question, since it doesn't really specify how many states the particle has been superposed in. I was thinking that the wave function encapsulates all possible states, so maybe if we project it onto the ground state I'll be able to find the probability?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are told the initial state is $\psi(x) = Nx$ for some constant $N$.

Answer (score 1):

Eigenstates of the 1-D infinitely deep square well form a complete basis in the Hilbert space. Thus, given the particle's wave function, there's only one way to write $\Psi(x)$ as a linear combination of the relevant eigenstates.

Especially, if you consider the Fourier expansion of the function $\Psi(x)=Nx$, you'll realize that the particle must have been superposed in all eigenstates. (Note that the eigenstates of the 1-D infinitely deep square well are given by trigonometric functions.)

All in all, we can determine the problem's answer by projecting the wave function onto the ground state.

Comment: How exactly is this projection achieved? Something like $\int_0^L \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin (\frac{\pi x}{L}) \cdot Nx dx$? That doesn't seem right in of itself but I'm guessing its something similar?

Comment: Yes, the formula you wrote is right. $N$ could be determined by normalizing $\Psi(x)$.

Comment: @Quantour so why exactly does it make sense that we have a $\sqrt{2/L}$ in front of our eigenstate? As can't the particle be in a superposition of other eigenstates? As I understand where $\sqrt{2/L}$ comes from if you find the normalisation constant but I thought that only works if we prepare our particle in that state and that state only.

Comment: Am I right in thinking of these eigenstates as entirely separate things, more so like unit vectors? And our wavefunction given to us is what distributes the probabilities?

Comment: I think you need to brush up with your concepts first..the factor you are discussing has nothing to do with the particular state you are understanding here.....